# Memory address wont load

Tags: memory, assembly

I am trying to move the value 0 into the address stored in ax (assume that this is writable for now).

```
mov ax, 0EC7 ; assume writable
mov BYTE    [ax], 0
```

But, nasm is giving me this error:

error: invalid effective address

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `eax` instead? or `mov BYTE PTR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16-bit addressing modes are quite limited. You can use an (optional) offset (a plain number), plus an (optional) base register (`bx` or `bp`), plus an (optional) index register (`si` or `di`). That's it.

In 32-bit addressing modes, any register can be a base register and any register but `esp` can be an index register. 32-bit addressing also introduces an (optional) scale (1, 2, 4, or 8) to be multiplied by the index register.

`[eax]` will work - even in 16-bit code. The assembler generates an "address size override prefix" byte (0x67). If the value in `eax` exceeds the segment limit (usually 64k), an exception is generated (not handled in real DOS - it just hangs), so be careful with it.